# TinyMCE - Word count - Ignore HTML, but don't cut it out when limit is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

This could be the biggest long shot question I have ever asked and I would really appreciate anyone's help with this prediciment.

I have a richtext editor (using TinyMCE) and currently it will ignore any HTML tags placed into the editor. The issue I am having is that when the limit goes over, it will trim the text and ends up cutting out all of the HTML tags originally placed in.

I need it to be able to ignore all HTML tags, but also keep it in when the limit goes over.

It's pretty frustrating as I can only ever get it to either ignore HTML, but cut it out when limit is over, or count the HTML tags and keep it in after the limit is reached. My client is adament that it needs to ignore HTML tags, but leave it in tact when it goes over.

Here is the code I currently have http://fiddle.tinymce.com/hYeaab

Again, any help is really greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing the "replace" method being passed within the limit_chars function.

```
limit_chars(input_name, char_limit, char_info,content.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, ''));
```

And matched it instead within the limit_chars function...

```
var textlength = text.length;
var num_breaks = (text.match(/\n/g)||[]).length;
var html = (text.match(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi)).length;
textlength = textlength - num_breaks - html;
```

Code can be seen here... http://fiddle.tinymce.com/iYeaab